# Get value from dictionary as an array in Swift 2

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I am relatively new to swift and I have a little problem here.
I have a JSON already serialized as a dictionary. This is how I get the dictionary

```
guard let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject] else {
                    print("Error trying to convert data to JSON")
                    completionHandler(nil, response, error)
                    return
                }
```

Here is my dictionary

```
{
  "count": "68",
  "earthquakes": [
    {
      "src": "us",
      "eqid": "b000gbf8",
      "timedate": "2013-04-19 03:05:53",
      "lat": "46.1817",
      "lon": "150.7960",
      "magnitude": "7.2",
      "depth": "122.30",
      "region": "Kuril Islands"
    },
    {
      "src": "us",
      "eqid": "b000g7x7",
      "timedate": "2013-04-16 10:44:20",
      "lat": "28.1069",
      "lon": "62.0532",
      "magnitude": "7.8",
      "depth": "82.00",
      "region": "Iran-Pakistan border region"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get those earthquakes as an array that I could iterate every item in it.

I try to create a temp var for that

```
let eqs = resultJSON["earthquakes"]
```

But, I can't iterate through `eqs`. My point is, I want to make an array that comes from that dictionary.

How is that possible? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key `earthquakes` contains the array which has `String` keys and values

```
if let earthquakes = result["earthquakes"] as? [[String:String]] {
    for earthquake in earthquakes {
        let lat = earthquake["lat"]!
        let lon = earthquake["lon"]!
        // get other values
        print(lat, lon)
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason for the _downcast_ with the [_type cast operator_](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338) is because [a dictionary's subscript returns an optional value](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html).

Comment: @alykhank The main reason for the downcast is that dictionary's subscript returns `AnyObject`

Comment: @vadian should we cast with `as? something` for every value in dictionary? Thank  you anyway.

Comment: The JSON reveals that all keys and values are `String` so the downcast to `[[String:String]]` is sufficient. And if all dictionaries in the array contain all keys (which happens quite often if the data comes from a SQL database) you can forced unwrap the values.

Comment: Thank you so much, @vadian.